# Running command in command prompt from c# code error

Tags: c#, windows, command-prompt

I'm trying to execute the following command in command prompt from my c# application and I keep getting the following output and it's not running the command I specified, any help or direction in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Env:

```
Windows 10
.Net Standard
```

Error:

```
Error loading resource: 0x00003afc
Error loading resource: 0x00003b01
```

Code:

```
     public void CacheKerbose()
       {
           try
           {
               var proc = new Process();
               var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", "/c" + "klist -li 0:0x3e7 purge");
               procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
               procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
               procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
               procInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
               proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
               proc.Start();
               proc.WaitForExit();
           }
           catch (Exception x)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
           }
       }
```

Comment: Two questions.  If you run your C# code without the `proc.Start();` statement, so you get the same errors?  And... If you run `klist -li 0:0x3e7 purge` from the command line do you get the errors?

Comment: @Flydog57 - no I only get the errors when I run the proc.Start(); - no It runs perfectly fine outside of running it in the application

Comment: More questions.  What kind of app is this (console, windows forms, etc)?  Is it .NET Framework or Core (.NET Standard doesn't really mean anything - it just means that the assembly can be loaded into either the Framework or Core).  What is your locale.  My guess is that something is trying to load an error message out of a resource file and failing.  Try looking at your process with SysInternals Process Monitor and see what it's trying to do.  The other thing to try is to take your code into a simple console app (just paste your code into Main) and see what happens

Comment: @Flydog57 its a Windows Form Application

Comment: In your processStartInfo, looks like you're missing a space between /C and klist task. The way you're writing it will send to CMD /CKlist. You actually can put the entire command in one set of quotes like this: "/C klist -li 0:0x3e7 purge"

Comment: @JonathanMonestel - I still have the same error unfortunately.